# wondering what happened to my python code that draw a checkerboard with turtle? any helps?

Tags: python

```
import turtle
def main():
    turtle.pensize(4)
    for x in range(5):
        for y in range(5):
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(x*50,y*50)
            turtle.pendown()
            if (x+y)%2 == 0:
                turtle.begin_fill()
                black_square(50)
                turtle.end_fill()
            else:
                turtle.begin_fill()
                white_square(50)
                turtle.end_fill()

def black_square(width):
    turtle.fillcolor('black')
    for x in range(4):
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.left(90)

def white_square(width):
    turtle.fillcolor('white')
    for x in range(4):
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.right(90)

main()
```

Current image:
[image: Image drawn by code]

Intended image:
[image: Intended effect]

My code won't draw a correct checkerboard pattern, but I wonder why every for loop my square black and white both executed at the same time? I am not asking for the correct code that will get me the correct checkerboard and I just want an explanation for the mistakes in my code.

Comment: if you can, please copy and paste my code and see what happen, i am sorry if i didn't describe it well

Comment: It's because you don't draw the white square the same way as the black one. Hint: change something in the last line of black_square function (or white_square)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to explain your mistakes without giving you the correct code, but I will try:

basically the mistake is that black_square and white_square are drawing squares at the same location. The starting point is 50 units apart, but because the squares are drawn in opposite directions (clockwise and counter-clockwise), the resulting area overlaps. black_square would draw a square below the starting point, while white_square would draw a square above its starting point.

Comment: thanks so much, i should had realize that my squares both are moving different direction..because my first pseudocode was to draw square horizontally with for loop but soon i find out the logic won't work. then i changed to current logic but too dumb i forgot to change that as well. lol

Answer (score 1):

@Samson is totally right. You are almost there but there is a small mistake. For black squares you are rotating left and for the white square you are rotating right. So basically white square instruction is overwriting the black squares. Keep same direction.

The end result is as below.
[image: Correct Checkerbox]